# How to convert OLE Automation Date to My sql date

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How to convert OLE Automation Date to a Mysql standard date type?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this

```
CREATE FUNCTION `OADateToDate`(rawvalue double) RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
DECLARE owhole  LONG;
DECLARE seltime  DOUBLE;
DECLARE seldate DATETIME;
DECLARE finaldate DATETIME;

SET owhole = CAST(rawvalue AS UNSIGNED)-1;
SET seldate = DATE_ADD('1899-12-30 00:00:00', INTERVAL owhole DAY);
SET seltime =  (rawvalue- owhole) * 24 * 60 * 60;
SET finaldate = DATE_ADD(seldate, INTERVAL seltime SECOND);

RETURN finaldate;
END
```

This will create a function called OADateToDate(). Then you can use it like any other MYSQL function. Hope this will help somebody.